# Switch to reserve battery automatically

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I'm trying to make a circuit which will switch to a battery automatically once the power goes out. This circuit is going to power my router and media converter.

I've never worked with electronics before, so I'd like to learn a few things:

1. Will this circuit even work?
2. If yes, will the switch happen fast enough for a router to continue working without interruptions?

[image: circuit]

- V1: power supply from the wall
- V2: battery
- R2: load itself (router + media converter, both require 12V and max
  current is 1.5A)

Comment: The simplest solution is to connect the two voltage sources through "decoupling diodes" (diode OR) to the load. See also [my Codidact paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/278933) for another simple solution.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist wouldn't "diode OR" drain battery even when the power supply is enabled? (given that their voltages are basically same)
The transistor + resistor solution is very interesting though. Which real-world transistors (like, their serial numbers) would work with such setup?

Comment: D.B., the "power supply from the wall" has to be a little (several hundred mV) higher than the backup voltage. It may not even have a diode if there is one inside it. The idea is that the backup source current does not flow back (into the main source). See, for example, this [All about paper](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/battery-backup-power-supplies/).

Comment: As fun as this may be, why not just buy a commercial UPS???

Comment: @Circuitfantasist the power supply from the wall is constant 12V, while the battery can vary from 10V to 13V, so it's a bit hard to achieve what you're proposing with higher voltage(at least I don't know how to do so with small loss in energy). My previous comment about "given that therir voltages are basically same" was purely theoretical, which might have been confusing, sorry about that

Comment: @KyleB in my area power outages can last a few days, so I need to cover at least that much time(since it can get worse), which isn't that easy to achieve with commercial UPS(or it can be quite expensive, given that a lot of people in my area are also looking for backup power options)

Comment: This is available off the shelf. just buy a burglar alarm power supply. and retire the original router power supply.   there id probably s product intented for routers available too.

Comment: @D. Balaban, Why not just do it and experiment? So it's just two diodes and a resistor connected to the sources and the load.  For the two cases (with and without main voltage), measure the source and load voltages and the voltage drops across the diodes... and think about it... It will be very useful for you (of course, if you want to understand it and not just solve your problem).

Comment: @Jasen almost all of the off-the-shelf solutions are gone due to the fact that millions of people are in the same situation as I am. Also it's not as interesting

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I did try to add resistor to lower the voltage of the battery, but I cannot come up with a more energy-efficient solution than the one I've posted above

Comment: millions of people? sounds like a political problem.

Comment: @Jasen perhaps, but it's not a topic of this question.

Comment: @D. Balaban, Here are some rough considerations for this simple solution: Mains 15 V, backup battery charged to 14 V, 3A diodes, 10 ohm resistor.  Voltage drop across the diodes 1 V, charging current (15 - 14)/10 = 100 mA.  Output voltage 14 V (when there is a power supply) and 13 V (when there is no power supply). Maybe I should write it in an answer...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist yes, taking a power supply with a higher voltage would solve this problem, but buying a new power supply makes this solution more complex than the one I posted in the original post. Thank you a lot for your comments, I'm especially impressed with single transistor solution :)

Comment: @D. Balaban, The problem is that there is a need of some difference between the two voltages to charge the battery and to switch diodes properly. Another problem is the relatively high voltage drop across the diodes (almost 1 V at this current).

Comment: Obviously, your idea is to attach a 12 V backup battery to the **existing** set of 12 V power supply and 12 V load; so there is no voltage difference... If only you could open the power supply and "trick" it into raising its voltage a bit... but that requires the circuit diagram....

Comment: @Circuitfantasist there is no need to charge the battery in this scheme, as I'm charging it manually with a specialized charger.

Using Schottky diode (1N5820) the voltage drop should be significantly smaller (~0.4V), according to the simulations.

Comment: @D. Balaban, This simplifies things. But the backup battery may end up with a higher voltage than the main source. Therefore, it does not need a Schottky diode.